# MKMapView returns the wrong latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta in regionDidChangeAnimated

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mkmapview

I'm attempting to talk to a web service for locations within the zoomed-in or zoomed-out area on an embedded MKMapView. In the regionDidChangeAnimated method of my view controller (this is the method that I use to trap any user gesture on the map), I call the following:

```
NSLog( @"latitude delta = %f", mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta );
NSLog( @"longitude delta = %f", mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta );
```

And the log entry says:

```
latitude delta = 0.000435
longitude delta = 0.001930
```

**However**, if I requery the lat/long dela manually after the regionDidChangeAnimated has fired (i.e. the user gesture is completed), I get the following:

```
latitude delta = 0.008415
longitude delta = 0.011932
```

Why is there a difference here? It doesn't matter whether this is a zoom in or zoom out gesture. There is always a difference. What's up with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted this bug to Apple, and was informed that this is a known issue. No workaround was suggested. :-(

Comment: Still no news about this bug ?

Comment: I'm finding a difference too.